# Water fountain laminar flow options using a 3d printer - can the default be significantly improved on?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

*I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but it is the best I can find!*

Laminar flow from a garden hose: All of the YouTube DIYs show a PVC pipe with the same sequence: Some sort of evener-outer (sponge), some sort of parallel-direction-maker (drinking straws), then a mysterious gap, then a small exit nozzle.

But if we are freed from the constraints imposed by slicing PVC pipe (a right cylinder) and drinking straws (equal length equal diameter tubes) and can do **whatever openSCAD + an average 3d printer allows us to do, does it help?**

My default guess is "very smart people have already thought about this, and the current best practice is there for really good reasons, not all of which the community cares to explain to a noob." *Which is cool.  But less fun.*

I know I want a low https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number.  I **also** know that math is not something I can digest and say "a cone would be better than a squared end"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pkWT.png)

1. Would a cone be better than a squared end? (if we can do cone-shaped straws)
2. Does that gap at the end matter, or is it just there because PVC pipe can't taper?
3. Is this all chasing a false premise that the default can be improved on?

[image: Options when 3d printing a laminar flow nozzle]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pkWT.png) You already figured that out from my (lack of) proper terminology

Comment: To my knowledge, the classiest laminar flow public fountains use a bundle of carefully machined pipes, analogous to a bundle of straws.  POssibly helpful:  https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/general/laminar-flow-nozzle-hard-build-145931/  and https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/5yi3g2/laminar_flow_nozzle_without_the_straws/

Comment: Heh. Second link is me.  First is great, thank you!